feedback request work items cannot be deleted
I was trying to delete a work item with feedback request but the system throws an error :
Error: Failed to delete work item: 19516. Error Details: VS402838: The work item 19516 cannot be deleted. Feedback Request work items cannot be deleted.
at o._handleSuccessfulCallback (https://tfs.intra.infineon.com/tfs/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-v5dXNA4dSJyMnNK25336gz-63SeoHZc9FwcE43Vz_Xk8=:875:6957)
at t.n (https://tfs.intra.infineon.com/tfs/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-v5dXNA4dSJyMnNK25336gz-63SeoHZc9FwcE43Vz_Xk8=:875:4047)
at s (https://tfs.intra.infineon.com/tfs/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-v5dXNA4dSJyMnNK25336gz-63SeoHZc9FwcE43Vz_Xk8=:270:20332)
at t.o (https://tfs.intra.infineon.com/tfs/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-v5dXNA4dSJyMnNK25336gz-63SeoHZc9FwcE43Vz_Xk8=:270:20592)
at n._func (https://tfs.intra.infineon.com/tfs/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vGHXheZgS3hyMaUbzls41rxhWznakbcMb0Pqw4EJu1BA=:77:217)
at n._invoke (https://tfs.intra.infineon.com/tfs/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vGHXheZgS3hyMaUbzls41rxhWznakbcMb0Pqw4EJu1BA=:77:5306)
at https://tfs.intra.infineon.com/tfs/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-vGHXheZgS3hyMaUbzls41rxhWznakbcMb0Pqw4EJu1BA=:77:4107

Currently, Azure DevOps doesn't support deleting Feedback Request work items. Ability to delete it (apart from witadmin) is on Azure DevOps's backlog. However, it is quite low in priority.
If you are using TFS2018 or earlier, you can use the witadmin destroywi command to delete the feedback request. See the detailed info from Remove work items permanently. This tool is not supported in Azure DevOps Services nor in Azure DevOps Server 2019 and onward, but it's the only way can delete the Feedback Request work items.
If you want such feature to delete Feedback Request, it's suggested to create a feature request here, which will help others to also possibly vote for it in order for the product team to prioritize it.
